# Why does flush() after a query cause a DB update?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I inherited an application that uses Hibernate which I had never used before. The 'standard' coding practice in this app (these guys were horrible programmers in many ways) was to create a session for every query/update, perform the query/update, then flush() and close() the session. Until now I didn't have an issue with this, but now I am. The situation is this:

1. Query the DB for a UserObject as they log in
2. Save the UserObject into web storage for the users webapp session
3. Use values in the UserObject to modify look/behavior of screens

2 is the new piece - previous code had saved some individual UserObject attribute values or queried the DB every time in every action after the user clicked something. But now that I'm storing/saving the UserObject in memory, other queries on this table/object cause the DB to hang on an update failure which Hibernate is performing during flush() after the query. Why is Hibernate performing a DB update when the object was simply queried?

I know I'm an old school programmer, where DB transactions were small ( open, read/write, commit/close ) and never had user interaction inside because this would escalate row, table, and tablespace locks. So maybe I'm not understanding how Hibernate persistence works and how it should be coded. Should flush() never be used after a query? Should there be only one 'session' object for each users webapp login-session? Is Hibernate persistence supposed to eliminate having to actually code an 'update' because it'll happen automatically under the covers? Meaning the coding model is to query hibernate/db/Java objects, have the user modify fields, have code that updates the Java objects and then one flush() + commit() method call updates everything in the DB?

** UPDATE **

Here's an example of the code that I inherited. There are a 100+ methods like this throughout the code for every DB object.

```
public static List<BeanObject> GetObjectList() {
    List<BeanObjec> list = null;
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    try {
        list = (List<BeanObject>) session.createQuery("from BeanObject").list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println("========="+e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return clist;
}
```

This has worked fine for months until recently when I tried to 'hold' onto one of these returned objects. Once that single object is held in web-session-memeory, another invocation to this method has the .list() call create 3 objects which is fine, but then the flush() call creates SQL UPDATES for all 3 objects! Why is hibernate UPDATING an object that wasn't modified?

Comment: Don't you think the Hibernate documentation might answer these questions? DB transactions should still be as short as possible (but not so short that it would compromise the coherence of the data). Flush is automatic. Saving the modified state is automatic. Each transaction should have its own session.

Comment: By 'each transaction should have its own session' you mean each web transaction or each user click that invokes a DB action, right? You don't mean each SQL statement should have its own transaction.

Comment: I mean each transaction, in the database, ACID, meaning of it. A statement is part of a transaction. An HTTP request can execute 0, 1 or more transactions. Typically 1.

Answer (score 1):

1. By default, `flush` before `commit` is redundant because it will happen anyway;
2. Hibernate doesn't `SELECT FOR UPDATE` by default;
3. you are correct that a single Hibernate Session should span one entire request processing. But that should be obvious from the business-level semantics of a single transaction per request. Anything else would be highly unusual, but still all the transactions would happen within the same Session, which most closely maps to one leased DB connection (although not 100%).

Comment: I posted some sample code above where, throughout this entire app, each SQL STATEMENT has its own session. I have a feeling that the writers of this code had no idea how to use Hibernate... But I still want to know why Hibernate is performing UPDATE statements during a flush() immediately after a query when no object was modified.

Answer (score 0):

To understand Hibernate persistence model you need to change your mindset from manual DML statements to [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

Hibernate enqueues all entity state transitions, only to [propagate them during a Session flush](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/). The AUTO flushing is going to flush before HQL/JPQL and Criteria query executions, but it [might not trigger a flush for native SQL queries](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush/).

The default flush-before-query is useful, since SQL queries should be run against the latest changes issued during your currently running transaction. You might only need a manual flush before native queries, but for entity querying, Hibernate should take care of it, if you stick with the default AUTO flush mode.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that blog - it is very helpful. Please look at my updates above.

Comment: That flush is useless in that particular use case. I can't imagine why to you see those updates in that method, since you open a fresh session and don't change anything, unless you use property-level access type, and the getters are returning different collection than the original ones.